# gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit using ES6

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, ui-grid

I am using `es6` with `angular 1.5` and `ui.grid`. While registering the `afterCellEdit` event on grid api, what should I pass instead of `$scope`?

```
export default class MyController{
// other codes skipped
registerGrdApi(gridApi) {
        this.grdApi = gridApi;
        gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit(this, this.afterCellEdit);
}

afterCellEdit(rowEntity, colDef, newVal, oldVal){
    // this.window.console.log(oldVal+" is changed to "+newVal);
}
}
```

We usually pass `this` as `MyController` class is the current scope, but I am receiving below error.

```
asked to listen on edit.on.afterCellEdit but scope wasn't passed in the input parameters.  It is legitimate to pass null, but you've passed something else, so you probably forgot to provide scope rather than did it deliberately, not registering
```

As suggessted in the above error message, when I use `null` as mentioned below

```
gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit(null, this.afterCellEdit);
```

it gives below error whenever I perform some edit on the grid, what is I am missing here ?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined
```

Comment: If the function requires the scope then pass the scope. I don't understand what's the problem. _"We usually pass this as MyController class is the current scope"_ No, it's not the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem resolved when passing `$scope` while injecting `MyController`. Later use that variable in `onRegisterApi` function. Below is the code that works.

`

```
export default class MyController{
// constructor
MyController($scope){
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: this.colDefs,
    data: this.gridData,
    enableFiltering: true,
    appScopeProvider: this,
    onRegisterApi: this.registerGrdApi,
    };
}
// other codes skipped
registerGrdApi(gridApi) {
    this.grdApi = gridApi;
    var _self = this.appScopeProvider;
    gridApi.edit.on.afterCellEdit(_self.scope, _self.afterCellEdit);
}
afterCellEdit(rowEntity, colDef, newVal, oldVal){
    // this.window.console.log(oldVal+" is changed to "+newVal);
}
}
MyController.$inject = ['$scope'];
```

`